# MUI Autocomplete with Modal

Tags: select, autocomplete, modal-dialog

I am using MUI Autocomplete component in an MUI Modal and my Autocomplete options are always open, when I scroll the Modal my Autocomplete options list did not hide under the Modal, how can I handle it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkgZh.png)

I tried to set the position relative for the options list, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you post the code of your component so it's easier to help you resolving this issue